# Alamofire 4 finish request in the background

Tags: ios, swift, background, request, alamofire

I'm using alamorefire to make calls to an API, but I figured that if I put the app in the background, the call will pause and I don't want that. I want it to load and then, when I bring the app to the foreground, I can use the requested data on the UI. How can this be done? At the moment I just do plain requests like this:

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: header())
            .responseJSON{response in switch response.result {
```

I've tried using the following alamofire configuration:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.cmpny.myapp.background")
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        manager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: headers())
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Request failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://url, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://url}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` for this purpose.

Apple doc:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpiratio

Similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751337/1689376

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: What if my task is already started when the app goes to the background? How can I make sure it finishes?