# Execute code in the background when push notification is received iOS15

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, geolocation, apple-push-notifications

I'm building an app which is running in the background and tracking significant location changes on the device.

Is it possible to send a push notification to the device and have the device send the current precise location to a server without needing the user to open the app so it runs in the foreground?

This [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43289458/5310637) doesn't seem to work anymore with iOS15. `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` does not seem to get called until I foreground the app. Is there a new method to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new feature **since iOS 15**: **Location Push Service Extension** (CLLocationPushServiceExtension - docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationpushserviceextension)). It is a power efficient way to query locations on iOS devices, **even when your app isn’t running**.

Please dive in into the docs and follow steps to configure Xcode project, add a Location Push Service Extension Target and implement Location Push functionality. Don't forget about proper entitlements and to request authorization for Location Services!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/creating_a_location_push_service_extension